# Silverlight XAP file security

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I’m using a standard ASP.NET login page to protect a Silverlight XAP file – I don’t want users to be able to download the XAP unless they login in.

To do this I added the following to system.web in the web application’s web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">   
   <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" timeout="30" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
   <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

If I use the application using the Visual studio development web server then everything works as I expect. However, if I use IIS then you can browse and download the XAP without logging in.

Am I missing something or is this not possible?

[image]

Comment: do you have runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests set to true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to protect your directory in IIS itself in order to deny the user. Here's some information that should help you out: [IIS Secure Content](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/583/secure-content-in-iis-through-file-system-acls/)

Answer (score -2):

To run Silverlight application, a browser need to download xap file. That's why it is impossible to protect your xap file from being downloaded.

Comment: The first part is true, i.e. run == download. However you can still protect the XAP file from being **both** downloaded and executed, e.g. by setting the web server file permissions where only authenticated users will be able to download (and run) the XAP file.